# Parcelable inheritance in aidl

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I want something like below in .aidl and use them in an android service.

```
abstract class sharp implements Parcelable {
}

class rect extends sharp {
}

interface IsharpMgr {
    sharp get();
}
```

In order to do this, the sharp class have to implements Parcelable. It is easy to override writeToParcel in rect but how should I add the "public static final Parcelable.Creator" in sharp?

in gen/IsharpMgr.java, that creator is called via sharp->Creator.createFromParcel. It's a static filed so I could not override it in rect.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Serializable instead of Parcelable? Serializable is incredibly easy to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: I had the names `sharp` and `rect` confused, so I've swapped them to avoid confusion**

You just implement it like this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Rect> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<Rect>() {
     public Rect createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new Rect(in);
     }

     public Rect[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Rect[size];
     }
 };
```

You aren't **overriding** the field in `Sharp`, because static fields cannot be overriden. You are **hiding** the field. That means if someone writes:

```
Parcelable.Creator<Rect> creator = Rect.CREATOR;
```

they get a different object than if someone writes:

```
Parcelable.Creator<Sharp> creator = Sharp.CREATOR;
```

**Note:** I took the liberty of capitalizing your class names `Rect` and `Sharp`. You should also do it. It will make your life easier and your code will look more like Java ;-)

**EDIT: Added some additional clarification after OP's comments**

I think I see your problem. You want to define an interface that passes a `Sharp` object, but you really want to pass a derived `Rect` object and this object is recreated as a `Sharp` object on the receiving end. It looks like AIDL doesn't support this kind of inheritance. However, what you could do is something like this (poor-man's factory):

In `Rect`:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(getClass().getName());
    // Write other instance variables
}
```

In `Sharp`:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Sharp> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<Sharp>() {
     public Sharp createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         String derivedClassName = in.readString();
         if (derivedClassName.equals(Rect.class.getName()) {
             // Create an instance of Rect and return that
             return new Rect(in);
         } else if (derivedClassName.equals(...) {
             // Possible other derived classes
         }
     }

     public Sharp[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Sharp[size];
     }
};
```

Note that the constructor

```
public Rect(Parcel in)
```

will get called with the class name String already removed from the incoming `Parcel`.

Comment: But when I use it in an AIDL file, it will generator code as below:if ((0!=_reply.readInt())) {
_result = TuningServiceParameters.CREATOR.createFromParcel(_reply);
}

Comment: public sharp get() throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
sharp  _result;
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_get, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();
if ((0!=_reply.readInt())) {
_result = sharp.CREATOR.createFromParcel(_reply);
}
else {
_result = null;
}
}
finally {
_reply.recycle();
_data.recycle();
}
return _result;
}

Comment: Yes, the new way just solved my problem, thanks. While, using reflex may be better.